# javascript video tag control buffering

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

**hi**
i was playing around with js and video tag in html5 
and i successfully achieved to seek the cursor at any point of time i want

now the task is more difficult, i want to control the buffering of the video

like this pic here
[what i want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuQkw.png)

```
my code is still looks very basic
```

```js
var video_length;
var buffer_area = [
  [0, 20],
  [50, 75],
  [80, 100]
];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <video width='440' height='250' src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" autoplay controls poster="posterimage.jpg">
      
    </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to directly affect what is buffered. I think the closest you can get is manipulating the video's current position to be within defined zones

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

var video_length;
var buffer_area = [
  [0, 20],
  [50, 75],
  [80, 100]
];

video.currentTime = buffer_area[0][0];

function set_time()
{
    //Just in case the first number is higher than 0
    if(video.currentTime < buffer_area[0][0])
    {
        video.currentTime = buffer_area[0][0];
    }

    //Make sure the current position is between the two numbers of a pair, and if not, bump it up to the next one
    for(var b = 0; b < buffer_area.length - 1; b++)
    {
        if(video.currentTime > buffer_area[b][1] && video.currentTime < buffer_area[b + 1][0]) video.currentTime = buffer_area[b + 1][0];
    }

    //Stop the video if the player tries to go beyond the last number
    if(video.currentTime > buffer_area[buffer_area.length - 1][1])
    {
        video.pause();
        video.currentTime = buffer_area[buffer_area.length - 1][1];
    }
}

video.addEventListener("timeupdate",set_time);
video.addEventListener("seeked",set_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean control the *look* of the progress bar when buffering?

That can be accomplished with the video's `playing` and `buffered` attributes

```js
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
var bufferBar = document.getElementById("bufferBar");
var bufferRanges = document.getElementById("bufferRanges");
var progressRanges = document.getElementById("progressRanges");

video.addEventListener("progress",function()
{
 bufferRanges.innerHTML = "";
 
 for (var b = 0; b < video.buffered.length; b++)
 {
  var startX = video.buffered.start(b) * (440/video.duration);
  var endX = video.buffered.end(b) * (440/video.duration);
  var width = endX - startX;

  var newRange = document.createElement("div");
  newRange.className = "bufferRange";
  newRange.style.left = startX + "px";
  newRange.style.width = width + "px";
  bufferRanges.appendChild(newRange);
 }
})

video.addEventListener("timeupdate",function()
{
 progressRanges.innerHTML = "";
 
 for (var p = 0; p < video.played.length; p++)
 {
  var startX = video.played.start(p) * (440/video.duration);
  var endX = video.played.end(p) * (440/video.duration);
  var width = endX - startX;

  var newRange = document.createElement("div");
  newRange.className = "progress";
  newRange.style.left = startX + "px";
  newRange.style.width = width + "px";
  progressRanges.appendChild(newRange);
 }
})
```

```css
#bufferBar
{
 width: 440px;
 height: 15px;
 background-color: #2c2c2c;
 position: relative;
}

.bufferRange
{
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #636363;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

.progress
{
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #e73853;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<video width='440' height='250' src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" autoplay controls poster="posterimage.jpg">
      
</video>
<div id="bufferBar">
 <div id="bufferRanges"></div>
 <div id="progressRanges"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's perfectly working but i need to manipulate the buffer ranges
for example: i want the player to buffer only from 0->10 sec and then buffer from 20->30 sec ... and the part from 10->20 i want the player to skip it